# Generating a number from an API call, then using the returned number as a parameter in another API call

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a "Show - Actor - Show" button, which displays a random show, then a cast member from that show, then another show with the same cast member.

I have succeeded in generating a random show ID, but I can't figure out how to pass that ID into the randomActor function since randomShow is not a function.

Ideally I want to use one button the searches for an actor or show depending on the previous search. Currently the issue is with my randomActor function. I am struggling to pass in the value of the randomShow search to the string template literal.

Any help/advice is much appreciated!

```
const randomButton = document.querySelector('#randomShow')
const randomShow = randomButton.addEventListener('click', async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const res = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${randomNumber}`)
    console.log(res.data.id);
    return (res.data.id)
})



const randomActor = randomActorButton.addEventListener('click', async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${randomShow.res.data.id}/cast`)
    console.log(res.data[0]);
    return (res.data[0])

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The eventListener will not return the result of the function in the listener

This works:

```js
const randomButton = document.querySelector('#randomShow');
let randomShow = "";
randomButton.addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("actor").innerHTML = "";
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  const res = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${randomNumber}`)
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = res.data.name;
  randomShow = res;
})


const randomActorButton = document.querySelector('#randomActor')
randomActorButton.addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (randomShow) {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${randomShow.data.id}/cast`)
    console.log(res.data)
    document.getElementById("actor").innerHTML = res.data[Math.floor(Math.random(res.data.length))].person.name;
  }
  else console.log("No show")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.min.js" ></script>

<button type="button" id="randomShow">Random show</button>
<button type="button" id="randomActor">Random Actor</button>

<span id="show"></span> <span id="actor"></span>
```